# Ultimate Member Wordpress plugin issue

Tags: wordpress, plugins, ultimate-member

I am not a coder at all. I help my mother in law build basic Wordpress websites for her and her friends. I use already developed plugins and I'm normally pretty good at problem solving but I am stumped. I am using Ultimate Member and Restrict for a login page and Accept Stripe for their payments. Everything was working fine but people were having issues so I wanted to update the instructions and everything went south. The register button stopped working and I cannot figure out how to fix it. Nothing is working and the plugins developers have been no help at all, pointing fingers to the other plugins and not actually helping me. Any suggestions?

I tried making a completely new registration form. I tried taking out the payment option. I figured just starting over would fix the issue but I was wrong.